# Ray trace проблема ближайшей точки пересечения

Tags: raytracing

Реализовываю алгоритм трассировки лучей. Первичный луч попадает на поверхность, из найденной точки пересечения выпускаем отраженный луч, но точка пересечения лежит в поверхности и отраженный луч пересекает эту поверхность, получается ближайшая точка пересечения там же откуда был испущен луч, как решается эта проблема?[image: Все, что черное, это точки где луч "застрял"]
Все, что черное, это точки где луч "застрял"

Comment: "**в** поверхности" - это как?

Comment: @MBo если это грань куба, например, то принадлежит плоскости грани

Comment: Ну и что? Новый (отраженный) луч начинается с параметра t=0 (или как он у вас там задан), ищете пересечение для t > 0, да и текущую плоскость вообще ни к чему рассматривать при поиске пересечений

Comment: @Mbo Ну я пробовал, брать исходную точку и получившуюся точку пересечения, сравнивать их (с учетом плавающей запятой) и не учитывать если эти точки "слишком близко"

Comment: Почему вы производите расчёт пересечения с текущей плоскостью?

Comment: @MBo да я бы рад этого не делать, но адекватного способа в голову не приходит

Comment: Как заданы плоскости и организована проверка? Если они в списке или массиве и проверка перебором, то исключайте текущий индекс из проверки

Comment: @Mbo ну вот это единственное, что мне пока в голову приходит, брать конкретный треугольник и выкидывать его из просчета, но для этого мне придется довольно сильно сменить архитектурно программу, поэтому я и решил спросить, мейби есть другие варианты, но походу придется переписывать

Comment: А что является результатом проверки - не номер ли треугольника?

Comment: @Mbo там собственно точка пересечения и "тело", конкретный, например, куб, с которым пересеклось, ну и нормаль конечно

Comment: ну в таком случае действительно только расстояние минимальное задавать

Answer (score 0):

Можешь добавить к точке испускания луча нормаль к этой поверхности, умноженную на очень малое значение, например:

```
ray_origin += normal * 0.0001
```

Тогда луч не будет *застревать* на самом объекте